# What if no Republican candidate gets a majority of delegates for president?

Tags: united-states, republican-party, republican-primary, rnc

I saw on Wikipedia when I was looking at the 2024 Republican Party primaries that one of the rules is to receive an outright majority of the votes cast by delegates at the national convention.

What happens if no candidate wins a majority of delegates? Does it go to the candidate who receives a plurality, or is there another round of voting?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Another round of voting is called until a candidate receives an outright majority vote of the delegates.

See the Republican Party's [*Rules of the Party*](https://prod-static.gop.com/media/Rules_Of_The_Republican_Party.pdf#page=46), adopted August 24, 2020 and amended April 14, 2022:

> 40. d)  When at the close of a roll call any
>     candidate for nomination for President of the United
>     States or Vice President of the United States has
>     received a majority of the votes entitled to be cast in the
>     convention, the chairman of the convention shall
>     announce the votes for each person receiving delegate
>     votes cast in accord with their respective state party
>     rules and state law. Before the convention adjourns *sine
>     die*, the chairman of the convention shall declare the
>     candidates nominated by the Republican Party for
>     President of the United States and Vice President of the
>     United States.
>
>     e) If no candidate shall have received such majority, the chairman of the convention shall direct the roll of the states be called again
>     and shall repeat the calling of the roll until a candidate shall have
>     received a majority of the votes entitled to be cast in the convention.

Comment: Interesting, so they just vote again with the exact same list of candidates (as opposed to just doing  a run-off between the top 2).

Comment: @quarague: if you look back in history, that's been the rule for a long time. Sometimes they had 30+ rounds. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1880_Republican_National_Convention

Comment: What actually happens is that there is horse trading. Often one of the candidates can  "drop out" and ask that their delegates vote for another candidate. After that I think it comes down to the delegates individual choice, although with considerable input from party leaders and the candidates.

Comment: "the 1924 Democratic National Convention holds the record as the longest ever, as divisions within the party concerning Prohibition led to 102 ballots between Alfred E. Smith and William G. McAdoo, before the relatively unknown John W. Davis was chosen as a compromise candidate on the 103rd ballot." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_nominating_convention

Comment: @ohwilleke I was going to mention that one as an example of how the delegates at a national convention are supposed to just keep voting and voting until there's finally a consensus -- until I saw you had already done so.

Comment: Note that this is the same as the election for Speaker of the House, for instance, as we have seen earlier this year: it took 15 votes to get a majority, and some consecutive votes (e.g. the 4th, 5th and 6th) were exactly identical. Most of the others had a few irrelevant changes in votes for minor candidates.

Comment: There are also other types of votes where it does not just go to a run-off with the top 2. The election of the leader of the Conservative party in the UK for instance has rules (which regularly change a bit) where on each vote the candidate with the least votes is eliminated until only two remain (the first rounds are from MPs, and the final vote by all members of the party).

Answer (score 7):

@cdjb's answer is better. This is supplementary. Read that first.

What cdjb describes has happened in the actual presidential contest. It's unlikely, but can happen. In 1824 Jackson entered with the most popular and electoral votes, but Adam's was elected presedent.

(Electoral College runs on the same principles, but is governed by different rules that basically do the same.)

Broadly, if you have delegates voting for the winner, require an outright majority to win, and have 3+ candidates, it's common to proceed to multi-round voting.

It's seen as important to have an outright majority to win so nobody can win by splitting their opponents. If Literally Hitler got 20% of the vote, but the rest were evenly split across 5 candidates, going to further rounds of voting might show 80% would prefer Bob over Hitler. These further rounds ensure the victor has more than minority support.

Subsequent rounds may have additional rules, often to cut down on the number of options to help consolidate the vote and get it closer to 50%.

(This is very related to runoff voting.)

Comment: The simplest rule is to always eliminate the candidate with the least votes. Most people would judge this as "fair" and it guarantees that there are never more than N-1 rounds, given N candidates.

Comment: That's why it's a common rule in runoffs, but it's not universal. It's probably my favorite, but remember that it's proven there are no completely fair voting systems.

Comment: @bharring: There are no completely fair voting systems that allow participants to *fully* express their preferences in a way that will be considered, but approval voting satisfies the "honesty" criterion.  If someone likes Bob better than Charlie, but things Alex is better than both, and David is inferior to both, the voter might achieve the best results by voting for both Bob and Charlie, neither Bob nor Charlie, or for Bob but not Charlie, but would never get a better outcome by voting for Charlie but not Bob, than by one of the other options.

Comment: Any voting system with just 1 voter is completely fair.

Comment: @Gantendo Arrow's theorem is, succinctly put, that the system is either unfair or a (de facto) dictatorship.  Yours would obviously be the latter kind.

Comment: @LawnmowerMan If the candidates are Hitler, Stalin, and Gandhi, and 45% of voters really hate Stalin, and mildly prefer Hitler to Gandhi, and 45% really hate Hitler and mildly prefer Stalin, and 10% prefer Gandhi, then Gandhi gets eliminated the first round.

Comment: @Acccumulation Well what is Gandhi expecting when 90% of the voters prefer not-Gandhi?

Comment: @Acccumulation sounds like a perfectly fair election to me. The problem isn't the elimination, it's the voters. I won't own that. If you allowed Ghandi to remain in the election and he somehow won, then a lot of people will decide that the election is manifestly unfair, no?

Comment: @LawnmowerMan Read up on the [Condorcet criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_winner_criterion). In either two-candidate subset, Hitler vs Ghandi or Stalin vs Ghandi, Ghandi would win 55% to 45%. 100% of voters agree that Ghandi is at least a decent compromise candidate. I would argue that any election system that does *not* have Ghandi win in this scenario is manifestly unfair.

Comment: But then you introduce the theory that you must convince your voters to not express a secondary choice, or failing that to have a secondary choice that has no support. Whichever way you go from there, it goes wrong. Read up on the Arrow proof - this has all been hashed out before.

Comment: @Douglas "100% of voters agree..." is unsupported.  No one has voted "Ghandi would be an acceptable compromise candidate".  For all you know everyone but the 10% considers Ghandi an unacceptable choice, and just finds the third party *even worse*.